# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException when programmatically setting android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple

Tags: android, listviewitem, checkedtextview

I'm trying to programmatically set the "android:checkMark" attribute on CheckedTextView items I have in a ListView. When running my application I get the following exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x101021a
```

The resource with ID #0x101021a corresponds to **android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple**, which is exactly the value I am passing to my CheckedTextView:

```
mCheckedTextView.setCheckMarkDrawable(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple)
```

Isn't this the way to do it from Java? I tried (and succeeded) to trigger the desired behaviour from XML layout:

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:id="@android:id/text1" />
```

The thing is that I don't know at compile time if it should be

```
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

or

```
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
```

Hence, I need to set these values at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me alot with a problem i had today.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would guess that programmatically setting an *attribute* reference rather than a *`Drawable`* reference is the problem.

In this case, `android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple` [corresponds to](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-4.2.2_r1.2/core/res/res/values/themes.xml#L140) `android.R.drawable.btn_check`, so you could try setting that instead.

---

Or, if you can obtain the attributes, you could call [`getDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getDrawable%28int%29) on the `TypedArray` to dynamically fetch the `Drawable` value.

**Edit:**
Since the value of `listChoiceIndicatorMultiple` depends on the current theme, you need to ask the current theme to resolve the reference:

```
int[] attrs = { android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple };
TypedArray ta = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
Drawable indicator = ta.getDrawable(0);
view.setCheckMarkDrawable(indicator);
ta.recycle();
```

Be sure to cache the drawables, rather than performing this manoeuvre for every item in your `ListView`.

That's just a very basic example, but it works with the default theme.  I'm not exactly sure what needs to be done to resolve `attrs` fully if you have a custom theme.

Comment: That's a really good answer (since I've already walked down that path :-), however, it seems like there is no "android.R.drawable.btn_check" drawable. If I browse the file system I do indeed find it (it's in the "[path_to_android_SDK]/platforms/android-9/data/res/drawable" folder and it's an XML file), but when writing my code accordingly I get compile errors complaining about "btn_check cannot be resolved or is not a valid field".

Comment: The other suggestion (the one about "getDrawable()") is, however, new to me. I'll have to do some "homework" on that one though, since I haven't done such a manoeuvre before :-)

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I've added a very basic code example that works for me.

Comment: Thanks! Your code works like a charm! I will most likely implement a fall-back solution for those cases where there is a custom theme on the device and no drawable for the "...Multiple" respective "...Single" indicators can be obtained from the theme. Thanks again for high quality help (I would up-vote this answer over and over again if I could :-)

Comment: A quick comment on @Christopher's caching suggestion: I haven't found a safe way of caching the drawables as recommended. If I do cache, it seems like all my list items will get the same state as the item I clicked on. And yes, I have called "indicator.mutate()". Currently I'm relying on my adapter and that it succeeds to reuse the "convertView" correctly when creating/reusing list items in order to reduce unnecessary drawable obtaining.

Answer (score 1):

If using the appcompat library simple alternatives would be:

```
setCheckMarkDrawable(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_btn_check_material);
```

or:

```
setCheckMarkDrawable(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material);
```